# If $E$ is open set, then every limit point of $E$ need not to be in $E$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

the set $E$ is said to be open set if every element $x$ in $E$  then $x$ is interior point in $E$, for example the open set (interval) $$I=(a,b)$$
the limit point $x$ of a set $E$ if there is a real number $r\gt 0$ $$ ( N_r(x)-{x})-\ E^c\neq \emptyset $$
 the set of all limit points of $I$ is the closed set (interval) $$I'=[a,b]$$ then $a$ is limit point of $I$ but $a$ is not in $I$ , thus don't every limit point of a set $E$ belong to $E$ , if was this case satisfied then every open set is closed set and the visa versa.
I need more information about this discussion.
and thanks advance

Comment: What is the considered topology on $\Bbb R$? The usual topology induced by the Euclidean metric? You need to be more specific about it to get an answer, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: Consider the topology induced by the discrete metric on $\Bbb R$. Then all subsets of $\Bbb R$ are open sets but none have any limit points.

Comment: Under the usual topology however, your claim is true. In fact, the sets that contain all their limit points are _closed_ sets. For an open set, or basically for any subset of $\Bbb R$, the topological closure operation unites the subset with all its limit points (it is denoted $\operatorname{cl}(A)=A\cup A'$) where $A'$ denotes the derived set (set of limit points) of $A\subset\Bbb R$

Comment: Thanks for advice, this discussion in real analysis , particularly in usual metric space.

Comment: Is your claim that every open set is closed, and every closed set is open, in any topology?

Comment: Y.Forman , no , this discussion at metric space in general, and it’s true if (X,d) is discrete metric space with R.